# Appreciation about a dead person

Tags: word-meaning

A Japanese writer OE Kenzaburo died weeks ago. [The Wall Street Journal](https://www.wsj.com/articles/kenzaburo-oe-in-memoriam-1935-2023-a0a86216?st=8iv18swhptvdjxz&reflink=desktopwebshare_permalink) published a column about that and showed a small box which reads

> APPRECIATION Kenzaburō Ōe 1935-2023

'Appreciate' and 'appreciation' have a few different meanings. I understood it as a dry mention of 'life span' because there were only the name and birth/death dates. But after I looked up it in dictionaries to confirm the meaning I got to know that there was not even a similar one.

Will someone confirm that the meaning of 'appreciation' above as just the same with (typical) 'gratitude' for his achievement? Is it usual, idiomatic or formal expression to thank a dead person like to honor with 'in memory of'?

Thanks from a non English speaker.

PS The following image is not seen in the web version and the column title of the paper version is 'The Disaster Artist' which is different from that of the web version.

[image]

Comment: Was this in a title, headline or subheading?  It might just be a house style of the WSJ for writing obituaries.  Did the text below the box contain writing that expressed respect and gratitude for the author?

Comment: @JamesK I added the image and the link. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a heading to me.

There is nothing very special here,  it marks this obituary as an "appreciation" of the author.  It isn't a particular idiom or formal expression in English, but the meaning is fitting enough:  It would catch the eye of anyone scanning the paper rapidly.  It may also be used in the paper version to fill up some space and avoid any blank spaces on the page. As a filler, the subeditor just needed some nice words, and these do the job.